# Error when selecting content from ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '14400 hour') format

Tags: php, mysql

So apparently i've stumbled upon a coding error when trying to select the time from my database.

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `added_time` > AddTime( CurTime(), '14400 hour' )
```

is the code, i'm trying to select all the videos posted 10 days (14400 hours) ago using the "added_time" format, because it worked for my previous coding but in this one it work work.

Shown below is a link to the image showing how my database structure for videos are shown.

http://i.imm.io/NURT.png

Edit: Previously i had this problem for retrieving and deleting bulletins posted 10 days ago, and this code worked, however this code apparently won't work when trying to retrieve the videos :/ I don't know why, they're using the same format.

See: http://i.imm.io/NUSW.png

Comment: What is the column type?

Comment: added_time is the colum and "videos" is the table

Comment: I mean the data type of added_time?  Is it a DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: $time = date("G:i:s T");
$date = date("D M d, Y, H:m");

Comment: So its a text type?  cast as a DATE with DATE(added_time)

Comment: that's how it looks when you're posting the time and date.

Comment: But database wise, here's the code: added_time varchar(100)

Comment: You're saving a date as a varchar? You need to alter that column, pronto.  Don't overcomplicate this for yourself, plus, it's best practice.

Comment: No, when posting it shows as: date("G:i:s T") but when it adds the time, it's inserted into added_time with varchar(100) format.

Comment: Yeah you need to change the column type. Date functions need a DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column type to function correctly.  You trying to add time to a random string currently.  I recommend the TIMESTAMP type and insert you data with the correct format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the actual date of `added_time`, then get the the date from 10 days prior to `NOW()`.

`WHERE DATE(added_time) = DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 DAY)`

You can change it to `<=` if you want to delete anything 10 days and greater.

--- Well now that we know one of them is a string and not a date field. Conver it.

```
// Change %Y-%m-%d to your date 
STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

After a little chat discussion and SQL Fiddlin' I got the answer, and it works for him. Cheers.

```
SELECT *
FROM videos_shared
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%a %b %d, %Y, %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d') 
<= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63eef/14

Comment: Didn't work, added_time is not a date. ("added_date") is a date.

Comment: alter it. Don't overcomplicate this.

Comment: It just returns with zero queries, it works, but it won't get posts older than 10 days. Seeing the format "added_time" is speaking of time like: 21:51:08 MST

Comment: added_date talks about: Mon Dec 03, 2012, 21:12 format and it's in the same table with added_time as another row/column.

Comment: use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function, example above.  Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: The code is fine, it is, but it returns with zero queries still when executed.

Comment: because you don't have an example exactly 10 days ago, likely.. change it to the `<=` to get some results.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `videos_shared` WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 DAY) - this is the code i've executed, but didn't work.

Comment: take out the DATE() function, not needed anymore.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20547/discussion-between-blahwhore-and-bigman)

Comment: Nice solution bigman, but this is madness.  Convert the type to DATETIME and format it when you insert.  All problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the full time format as:

```
  > SUBTIME( CurTime(), '14400:00:00.000000' )
```

or alternatively (substract 10 days as below:),

```
 > SUBTIME( CurTime(), '10 00:00:00.000000')
```

Refer the documentation here -> [**SUBTIME()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime)

Comment: This selects the whole column but doesn't retrieve dates that are 10 days old.

Comment: subtime won't work with a date format like: Mon Dec 03, 2012, 21:12

Comment: @Blahwhore You may want to use `DATE_FORMAT` to match the format.